# code=1200 error after upgrading Cassandra to 3.11.3

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have just inherited a system with 3 nodes, 2 in one datacenter with a replication factor of 2 and 1 one in a second datacenter with a replication factor of 1.  The system was upgraded from Cassandra 3.9 to Cassandra 3.11.3. Since the upgrade any queries in cqlsh return the error

```
ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 2, 'consistency': 'LOCAL_QUORUM'}
```

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this problem or where I should look to identify the problem?

edit:
I retried my query with a consistency of one but still received the error

```
ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out - received only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

Comment: Do you see any issues via `nodetool status`?  Also, querying a DC with a RF of 2 at LOCAL_QUORUM, isn't a good idea.  After all, "QUORUM" of 2 is...  2.

Comment: Also, 3.11.3 has a bug which essentially prevents reads after a DELETE operation is run (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14672).  It was a show-stopper for us.  Try rolling back to 3.11.2, and see if that helps.

Comment: @Aaron nodetool status shows all 3 nodes as being up and normal.  The only thing that looks a bit strange is the all claim to own 100% but they have different loads.  219.15 GiB, 227.37 GiB, 221.39 GiB.

Comment: The different loads is normal.  In fact, I'd be shocked if they were *ever* the same.  And 100% ownership is due to a calculation based on RF and token range percentage.  As your data centers have 2 & 1 nodes and a RF of 2 & 1 that 100% adds up.

Comment: Just curious, but what is the query?

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  I'm not sure downgrading is an option as we moved from Cassandra 3.9.

The query is a simple select count(*) from ablog where cus_id =100;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting too long for comments...

There are a few things that could be causing this.

**1 - How large is the largest partition?**  I'd check that with the following:

```
bin/nodetool tablestats yourKeyspaceName.ablog | grep "partition maximum"
```

If this comes back with something in double-digit GB range, you're in trouble.

**2 - Are there any tombstones?**  You can check that with a similar command:

```
bin/nodetool tablestats yourKeyspaceName.ablog | grep "tombstones"
```

If that comes back with numbers in 3 or 4 digits, that could be a problem.

**3 - Downgrading to 3.11.2** . 3.11.2 and 3.11.3 use the same SSTable format.  It's just a matter of switching-out the binaries.  Download/untar 3.11.2, move the conf dir in from the 3.11.3 directory, and it should be fine.

I only suggest this, because you could be running into [CASSANDRA-14672](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14672).

**4 - LOCAL_QUORUM w/RF=2**  As I mentioned in the comments, querying at LOCAL_QUORUM with a RF < 3 isn't any different from querying at ALL.  Cassandra computes quorum (majority) as follows:

QUORUM = (RF / 2) + 1 = (2 / 2) + 1 = 2 (replicas need to respond)

Seriously, you're not gaining *anything* by doing this.  It only makes sense to do when you have a RF of 3 or more:

QUORUM = (RF / 2) + 1 = (3 / 2) + 1 = 2 (replicas need to respond)

And actually, querying at QUORUM with RF=2 hurts you, as you cannot tolerate a single node being down.

Comment: Thank you for the help.

I've checked all my tables and the largest is 0.96GB and for tombstones I'm only seeing  1 or NaN.  I have a feeling downgrading is my only option.

Comment: @RuthBurns a 900+MB partition can be problematic if you're trying to query it all at once.  Maybe try your query with a `LIMIT 1` on the end?